# How to write a Shell Script that will count the occurrences of each number in a file?

Tags: bash, uniq

This question was asked by the interviewer today. Suppose there is a file named "Myfile.txt" and it's contains are as below:(not necessarily in one line)

```
1 3 4
4 1 5
1 9 8
3 2 1
6 0 0
3 4 5
7 8 9
```

I want to write a script that will tell me which number has how many occurrences in that file. You can see it has numbers from 0 to 9. As you can see "1" is repeated 4 times in this file, the output should tell me that "The number 1 is used 4 times in this file."

Comment: Should this be in python or bash or does not matter?

Comment: Bash Script only

Comment: My answer to this interview question would be "Why?"

Answer (score 3):

If the file can have multiple numbers per line, it is simpler to change that into one per line first and then count. For example:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file| sort | uniq -c
  2 0
  4 1
  1 2
  3 3
  3 4
  2 5
  1 6
  1 7
  2 8
  2 9
```

If you really need verbose output, you could further parse that to:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file| sort | uniq -c | while read cnt num; do printf 'The number %s appears %s times in the file\n' "$num" "$cnt"; done
The number 0 appears 2 times in the file
The number 1 appears 4 times in the file
The number 2 appears 1 times in the file
The number 3 appears 3 times in the file
The number 4 appears 3 times in the file
The number 5 appears 2 times in the file
The number 6 appears 1 times in the file
The number 7 appears 1 times in the file
The number 8 appears 2 times in the file
The number 9 appears 2 times in the file
```

Or:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file| sort | uniq -c | awk '{print "The number "$2" appears "$1" times in the file"}'
The number 0 appears 2 times in the file
The number 1 appears 4 times in the file
The number 2 appears 1 times in the file
The number 3 appears 3 times in the file
The number 4 appears 3 times in the file
The number 5 appears 2 times in the file
The number 6 appears 1 times in the file
The number 7 appears 1 times in the file
The number 8 appears 2 times in the file
The number 9 appears 2 times in the file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' \
     '{ n[$1]++ };

      END {
        for (i in n) {
          print i":",n[i]
        }
      }' debasish.txt
```

(this is a one-liner, with added newlines and indenting for readability)

Set the record separator (`RS`) to 1-or-more of any kind of whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc), and then keep count of each number seen in the array `n`.  Print the total for each element of `n` at the end of the input.

Output:

```
0: 2
1: 4
2: 1
3: 3
4: 3
5: 2
6: 1
7: 1
8: 2
9: 2
```